# "First steps with PDL" image created with Gnuplot differs from the one in PDL Book

Tags: perl, gnuplot, pdl

I found an example from http://pdl.perl.org/?page=FirstSteps that is:

```
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::Simple
pdl> imag (sin(rvals(200,200)+1)
```

I tried to run this example but [unsuccessfully](http://blogs.perl.org/users/zubenel/2020/02/struggle-getting-pdl-book-example-to-work-on-windows-10.html). As a consequence to that I tried to adjust the example that it would work with Gnuplot on Windows:

```
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot;
pdl> gplot(with => 'image', sin(rvals(200,200)+1) );
```

However, the resulting plot differs from the one that is given in PDL Book as it contains additional "V" form blue stripes:

[image]

For comparison image from PDL Book looks much cleaner:

[image]

I do not know what caused the difference.

Comment: The choice of colors affects our perception.

Comment: Which backend did `PDL::Graphics::Simple` use? There should be terminal output describing the backend. On my machine I got output: `Trying gnuplot (PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot)...ok` so it used the `PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot` backend.

Comment: The problem was to make this example to work on Windows. I was able to do it with `PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot` directly but not with `PDL::Graphics::Simple`. Because of that I compare the image I got to the one that is shown in PDL book.

Comment: How did you install `gnuplot` on Windows?

Comment: I installed Strawberry Perl with PDL version 5.30. Apparently it contains Gnuplot as I get no error with `use PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tried this with Gnuplot 5.2, bleeding-edge PDL, latest PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot (PGG) and PDL::Graphics::Simple (PGS). I get the same results as you for PGG, and for the book with PGS.

The way to make the colour-scheme be the same in both is to change the Gnuplot invocation to supply plot-options first:

```
pdl> use PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot
pdl> gplot({clut => 'sepia', colorbox => '', justify =>1}, with => 'image', sin(rvals(200,200)+1))
```

since, for better or for worse, PGS defaults to a sepia-tone. The `colorbox` option is the colour-scale, and if it's not there and you want the data to still be square, you have to add a true `justify` value.